# How to use a package name independent of the directory structure?

Tags: java, netbeans, package, directory-structure

I want a Java application to have a directory structure like the following (like maven):

```
src
  main
    java
      org
        example
```

When I add a new Java class called `NewClass` using the Netbeans IDE, it creates the package statement in `NewClass.java` as `package main.java.org.example;`.

If I remove `main.java.` from the `package` statement I get the error `Incorrect package`.

I do not want `main.java.` in the `package` statement, but I do want my directory hierarchy as mentioned above.

How do I get the package naming and the directory structure to play along?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your source directory from `/src` to `/src/main/java`

Comment: Do you mean the "Source Package Folders" in the "Project Properties" dialog?

Comment: Yes, that's what the answer means.